# IOS7 - SLComposeViewController - Include links / Images?

Tags: ios, facebook, twitter, slcomposeviewcontroller

I'm building an IOS7 Native app on behalf of a client - its for Fitness Instructors.

The brief requests that the clients can socially share progress updates  - which include a link to the instructors site to help promotion, for example - ['Joe ran 3000 miles with the help of Debbie Personal Trainer'](http://www.trainerdebbie.com) and ideally a little pic of the trainer.

I've looked at the `SLComposeViewController` and can easily create the tweet string but I don't know how to add a URL and image to this - does anyone know if its possible?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Import framework `<Twitter/Twitter.h>` and `<Social/Social.h>`.

```
-(void)sendFacebook:(id)sender {

    SLComposeViewController *composeController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    [composeController setInitialText:@"look me"];
    [composeController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
    [composeController addURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"]];

    [self presentViewController:composeController animated:YES completion:nil];

    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
        if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
            NSLog(@"delete");
        } else  {
            NSLog(@"post");
        }

    //    [composeController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
      };
        composeController.completionHandler =myBlock;
}

- (void)sendTwitter:(id)sender {

    SLComposeViewController *composeController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

    [composeController setInitialText:@"look me"];
    [composeController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
    [composeController addURL: [NSURL URLWithString:
                                @"http://www.apple.com"]];

    [self presentViewController:composeController
                       animated:YES completion:nil];

    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler myBlock = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){
        if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) { 
            NSLog(@"delete"); 
        } else {
            NSLog(@"post");
        }
     //   [composeController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:Nil];
      };
        composeController.completionHandler =myBlock;
}
```

Comment: top notch cheers! - only slight issue is I get a 'no visible @interface for SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler declares the selector dismissviewcontroller:animated

Comment: @Dancer i'm sorry, I am confused. I edited my answer, look at the first few lines, I changed the import to do

Comment: its the line -  [composeController dismissViewController:composeController Animated:YES completion:Nil]; that is erroring for me with the above - if i comment it out it still works though..

Comment: actually - ignore - i cut and paste the same line from the twitter method and it works fine - must have been a typo somewhere - thanks very much for your help..

Comment: @Dancer I'm looking at now, and it is precisely the error that you have noticed .. now edited the reply ..  thank's you're welcome!

Comment: Thanks, this saved me from having to do a lot of experimentation!

Comment: This answer should remove the "dismissViewControllerAnimated" line due to iOS7 specific instructions in the docs:
"In iOS 7 and later when compiled with the iOS 7 or later SDK you must not dismiss the SLComposeViewController in your completion handler—the system will do so automatically."

Answer (score 3):

This is almost the same answer as llario, but follows Apple docs instructions and employs defensive coding with some additional error checking.

```
#import <Social/Social.h>

if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]) {
    SLComposeViewController *composeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
    if (composeViewController) {
        [composeViewController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage"]];
        [composeViewController addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
        NSString *initialTextString = @"Check out this Tweet!";
        [composeViewController setInitialText:initialTextString];
        [composeViewController setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
            if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultDone) {
                NSLog(@"Posted");
            } else if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
                NSLog(@"Post Cancelled");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Post Failed");
            }
        }];
        [self presentViewController:composeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```